# laravel livewire showing Constant expression contains invalid operations, how to fix this error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, livewires, laravel-livewire

**showing Constant expression contains invalid operations**

i am new in laravel livewire  when i was trying to pass function value  it showing

> Constant expression contains invalid operations.

**im trying this function**

```
'suppliers_master_id'        => $this->generateRegistrationId(),
```

**my code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Purchase;

use App\Supplier;
use Livewire\Component;

class AddSuppliers extends Component
{

        public $form = [
        'supplier'          => '',
        'email'              => '',
        'phone'              => '',
        'address'            => '',
        'city'               => '',
        'state'              => '',
        'pincode'            => '',
        'GSTIN'              => '',

        'suppliers_master_id'        => $this->generateRegistrationId(),


    ];

    public function submit()
    {
        $this->validate([

            'form.supplier' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'form.email' => 'required|email',
            'form.phone' => 'required|string|max:10',
            'form.address' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'form.city' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'form.state' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'form.pincode' => 'required|string|max:6',
            'form.GSTIN' => 'required|string|max:255',


        ]); 


     Supplier::create($this->form);
     session()->flash('message', 'Supplier Added  successfully .');

     return redirect()->to('/addsuppliers');
    }


    function generateRegistrationId() {
    $id = 'SIIT_' . mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999); // better than rand()

    // call the same function if the id exists already
    if ($this->registrationIdExists($id)) {
        return $this->generateRegistrationId();
    }

    // otherwise, it's valid and can be used
    return $id;
}

function registrationIdExists($id) {
    // query the database and return a boolean
    // for instance, it might look like this in Laravel
    return Supplier::where('suppliers_master_id', $id)->exists();
}

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.purchase.add-suppliers');
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a livewire problem, you are not allowed in PHP to call a function to initialize a property.

In regular PHP you would assign this inside your `__construct()` method.

Since Livewire works a bit differently you have to use `mount()` instead.

```php
public function mount()
{
    $this->form['suppliers_master_id'] = $this->generateRegistrationId();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you're using the `$rules` (default) property.

In that case, you can use the `rules()` method, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64989667/1536077