# Laravel Livewire - Constant expression contains invalid operations in $rules property

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-livewire

I tried to define some validation rules in my `livewire` component to validate some FormData:

```
protected $rules = [
    'website' => 'url|nullable',
    'zipcode' => 'regex:/\b\d{5}\b/|nullable',
    'founding_year' => 'required|digits:4|integer|min:1700|max:2020',
];
```

That work's very well until I need to validate against the value of a variable or a dynamic value in general.

E.g.: Changing the `max` property from hardcoded **2020** to the **current year**:

```
 protected $rules = [
   ...
   'founding_year' => 'required|digits:4|integer|min:1700|max:'. date('Y'),
];
```

Unfortunatelly this resolves in an exception:

> Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
>
> Constant expression contains invalid operations

Has someone an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't call functions or methods when declaring the value of a property directly in PHP.

With Livewire, you can specify a `rules()` method which returns the rule-array instead - this allows you to use functions in the rules. Internally, Livewire will now run the result of that method instead of grabbing the protected `$rules` array. This means you can still hook into the `$this->validate()` and `$this->validateOnly()` methods Livewire ships with.

So instead of defining your `protected $rules;` attribute, declare the `rules()` method,

```php
public function rules() 
{
    return [
        'website' => 'url|nullable',
        'zipcode' => 'regex:/\b\d{5}\b/|nullable',
        'founding_year' => 'required|digits:4|integer|min:1700|max:'.date("Y"),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Qirel, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Qirel, didn't know can use `rules()`, guess it's not covered in Livewire docs